# Как лучше передать файлы на сервер?

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

подскажите пожалуйста, с точки зрения скорости и нагрузки на сервер как лучше передавать файл?
Переводить его через js в blob и передавать на сервер, где сохранять, или же перевести в base64 через тот же js, затем на стороне сервера декодировать строку в файл и уже сохранить сам файл?

Comment: Просто выполните оба способа и сравните их друг с другом, наверное?

Comment: Однако здравый смысл подсказывает, что кодирование-декодирование туда-сюда будет создавать лишнюю и бессмысленную нагрузку

Comment: Я тоже так думаю